# How to implement a forced single click binding in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

What is the best way to force a single click on a binding (disabling method call for 1 second after click) in Aurelia.

In knockout I would have created a new custom `singleClick` binding but in Aurelia i'm not sure I can do this.

Should I look at building my own binding behaviour something like `click.delegate="onClick() & prevent-double"`

Can I use an existing binding behaviour something like throttle or debounce `click.delegate="onClick() & throttle"`

Is a custom element the answer, creating a new `single-click` button that takes an onclick method and disables the button for a second when clicked?

Comment: Do you want to physically disable the button? Or just stop the button firing the logic in your `onClick()` method?

Comment: Ideally the second, then I could apply it to any click binding

Comment: I don't think binding behaviour will allow you to achieve that to be honest - as the behaviour won't necessarily be called when the button is clicked, but just when the binding/unbinding of the function occurs. A custom element containing the logic might be your best bet.

Comment: yes this is what i feared. When i tried, the behaviours bind / unbind didn't even seem to be hit from my click.delegate. I can definitely do it with the element so will go with this for now.

Comment: click.delegate=“foo() & throttle:1000”

Comment: @JeremyDanyow I have used this a few times now, you should make it an answer so I can accept :)